# Equivariant Formula for High Dimensional Isolated set

Tags: equivariant-cohomology, equivariant

The **Atiyah-Bott-Berline-Vergne-Witten localization formula** says 
$S^1$ acting on compact manifold $M$ isolated fixing points. And for a closed equivariant  form $\omega$, then
$$(2\pi)^{-\frac{\dim(M)}{2}}\int_M\omega=\sum_{p\in isolated~ point}\frac{\omega^0(p)}{\det^{1/2}(L_p)},$$
where $L_p$ denotes the induced action on $TM$.

**Q**:

- If the isolated-point set is a high dimensional submanifold, are there some results about the Berline-Vergne?
- In the research of the localization of equivariant differential forms, are there some open problems?

Comment: Theorem 4.1 http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~dgreb/localisation.pdf

Comment: See paper of Atyah and Bott in 82

Comment: Yes. In the Duistermaat and Heckman's second paper, they generalized the DH-localization formula to the high dimensional case. This could answer the second question.

Comment: @DLN, I'm very interested in your second question: what are  open questions about localization theorem in equivariant cohomlogy, have you got answer for this question ?